# Enable / Disable columns in Intractive Grid conditionally Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I need to Enable/Disable some columns in Intractive grid on conditionally.

For ex:

If my Grid is having columns like

If status is Approved then user can edit the columns and modify, if the status is rejected or cancelled the column should disable automatically..

**Status     Name   Dob   Mobile

Approved     enable the following column to modify or edit

Rejected     disable all the columns name,Dob,mobile

Cancelled    disable all the columns name,Dob,mobile**

if its rejected or cancelled we are not entering or modifying those records

Answer (score 0):

In 21.2 it is possible to create a dynamic action on change of "Status" with action "Disable". Set the action to "Fire on initialization" to ensure the columns are disabled on load and make sure to create an opposite action. On the dynamic action set a client side condition of "Item = Value".
In your case, create a dynamic action with client side condition Item = Value for status "Approved", a true action to enabled the columns and a false action to disable the columns.
I can't test this on earlier versions, but this functionality has been around for a while.

Comment: Hi i tried like this, but in my scenario i have item = value (' approved, pending, draft, rejected, cancelled and so on), for approved/draft/pending it should enable for rejected, cancelled and so on it should disable

Comment: There is a condition "Value in list" I believe - did you try that ?

Comment: i am not aware of that , let me check and try